# How to specify checkbox data for saving to a bit field

Tags: asp.net

If a checkbox produces TRUE or FALSE, how do I convert to 1 or 0 to save the value to the database?

ASP.NET

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbTermsandcond" runat="server" />
```

C#

```
    BTermsandcondParam = new SqlParameter();
    BTermsandcondParam.ParameterName = "@BTermsandcondParam";
    BTermsandcondParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Bit;
    BTermsandcondParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    BTermsandcondParam.Value = cbTermsandcond. ???  ;
```

EDIT:

I wrote this which worked.  But is there a simplier way?

```
    if (cbTermsandcond.Checked == true)
    {
        BTermsandcondParam.Value = 1; 
    }
    else
    {
        BTermsandcondParam.Value = 0;
    }
```

Regards
Tea

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667004/write-bit-value-to-database

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744094/inserting-value-from-checkbox-template-field-into-sql-database-field-type-bit?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BTermsandcondParam.Value = cbTermsandcond.Checked
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm really rusty with my coding, catching up.